# Android Cloud Sql

Tags: javascript, java, android, sql, google-app-engine

**Android App using google SQL Cloud**

I have written a simple application in Android Studio

1. Activity Main.xml
2. Actiiviy Main.java

The application Takes in three (3) text fields:

1. A name Id which is hidden from user view and not editable.
2. A First name
3. A last name

I am unable to figure out how to connect to the database from the app. I know it requires the use of app engine and cloud endpoints.

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of a step by step guide aside from the Google developers documentation on mobile application using google sql back end.  Thank you

A how to on inserting into a google cloud database and retrieve from a google cloud database would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue as you!

After some researches i find that i can add "a Cloud Endpoints Module" in Android Studio. And here's the Google documentation for doing so: 
[Cloud Endpoints Support](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/endpoints/)

I succeed to deploy my endpoints module locally and deploy it to App Engine.

The problem is that Endpoints use Datastore for storing data (it's not a relational database) and i didn't find a way to connect my Endpoints to Cloud SQL neither. There's no documentation for doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your timely response. I believe that it is possible to do where you code the endpoint module to app engine and allow the the communication to be a web based application. so in the mobile app you would send data from input fields to the app engine web application jsp page which will then perform the insert or retrieval from the database on a web application server side level and then down to mobile app.

Comment: google tutorials on this process or any tutorial does not exist yet. Google documentation for this process will need to be a more simple break down almost spoon feed mentality (show me the basics) approach step by step. Mobile app --> endpoints --> app engine in detail for simple practical SCRUD operation not a hello world application. This technology has the potential to spark heavy idea driven application but with out proper documentation or tutorials it will go nowhere.

Comment: Yes, i'm totally with you in this. An official Google documentation describing the whole process is needed or at least something to guide us through it.